# Correct content type for html use?

Tags: content-type, html4

I was using XHTML on my website but that completely destroyed jQuery and its plugins.
Therefore, I want to go back to html 4. I am defining some custom attributes for my html, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" [ 
      <!ATTLIST mytag myattribute CDATA #IMPLIED> 
 ]>
```

This seems to be valid html for, but when I pass such a page from my server with a content type of text/html, my browser displays ']>' - it can't parse the doctype properly.
Is there a different content type I should be using?

Comment: I can duplicate this error on jsfiddle, but it works fine locally using Chrome 13. Is there any particular reason you are including the <!ATTLIST> meta data tag in your doctype? Your code works without it. Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Perception/fvxA2/

Comment: yeah well i am adding custom attributes to my div tags. if i don't add the <!attlist>, the document doesnt validate..

Comment: i really want to use xhtml, and i've tried it, but it messes up my jQuery and javacsript - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045253/jquery-xhtml-compliance. xhtml would be perfect, but i cannot seem to make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

[From A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customdtd/)

> If you run such a file through the W3C validator, you find that it
>   validates wonderfully well. If you download the sample files for this
>   article and validate file internal.html, you can see this for
>   yourself. Unfortunately, when you display the file in a browser, the
>   ]> shows up on the screen. There’s no way around this bug, so this
>   approach is right out.

So this basically isnt going to work.  To get it to work you need to copy the DTD you want the server/local machine, edit it appropriately and put it in a publically accessible place. See the article for more detail.

As far as jQuery is concerned, it should work fine if you quit trying to customize the DTD in the fashion that you are. Im not sure about using a custom DTD as I have never done it, but just adding the attributes to the elements and not defining them in the DTD shouldnt cause a problem with jq. Granted the document wont validate, but validation is just a tool and not overly important in the grand scheme of things.